# mixed data in mongodb and mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I read a lot about the possibility of combining MySQL and MongoDB and the feasibility of this idea.
in my work, I intend to design a hybrid database: in MySQL table user(userid, firstname, lastname, age, gender) to store user information and in MongoDB a forum collection. Forum{forumid, userid, datef, category, bodyf, comments=[{commentid, userid, bodyc, datec}] to store disucssion informations.
So my questions: how can I have the suitable and referenced userid in forum and comments collections? should I duplicate the user table in MongoDB again? do my idea not complicate thinks for future analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Oracle in the MySQL org

I don't see an easy way of doing that and I think you will end up will a lot of synchronization issues if you go down that route. Maybe you can drop MongoDB altogether since you can also use MySQL (5.7.12 or higher) as a [document store](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store.html).

Sorry if this does not help and dropping MongoDB is not an option.

Comment: But many projects combines two database schema. As an example, in the Edx platform: user data are on MySQL and forums are on MongoDB. I asked how each of them have a reference to something outside the database?

Comment: I don't know if they "combine" the schemas. There are a lot of people mixing up engines with polyglot architectures (via microservices) and the like, and to some extent, some hybrid models where usually there's a strict separation between relational data and schemaless data.

However, looking at your question, you kind of want to have cross referencing between both kind of entities, which is a hard problem to solve if you need referential integrity (not impossible though).